# SharePoint Online - What are the implications of disabling the - "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode"?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have restricted user access to various libraries on our SharePoint online site, including the Pages library. The SharePoint site is open to only few users whereas the Pages library is open to a more broader set of audience. Users who have access to just the Pages library, but not to the site, can navigate to all the pages in the library but they are not able to see the Global navigation bar or the Quick Launch.

I believe that i can resolve this if I disable the "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" feature  as described [in this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/3039997/users-can-t-access-a-shared-folder-in-sharepoint-online). I have tried looking for many articles over the internet but I am unable to find a clear answer for the implications of disabling the - "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode".

I would greatly appreciate any inputs on this.